# how to uninstall viber completely from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, viber

How can i uninstall viber completely from Ubuntu 14.04? I did not find any option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Viber is available as a .deb package and also as tarball. If you installed viber through the .deb package, then you can easily uninstall it using `sudo apt-get remove viber`

But instead, if you installed through the tarball, then you must have extracted the viber files into a single folder such as /opt/Viber. Just delete that folder and any .desktop files (shortcuts) that you created for it.

In addition, Viber user configurations are stored in `~/.ViberPC`. You can choose to delete that as well. Note that if you do this, the next time you install viber, you would have to make any customization you made this time , again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to uninstall **Viber** but keep the configuration files in case you will install it again in the near future, use :

`sudo apt-get remove viber`

In case you want to uninstall **Viber** and DO NOT keep the configuration files, use :

`sudo apt-get purge viber`

Answer (score 2):

1- Installed by apt-get:

```
sudo su
apt-get remove --purge viber
```

2- Installed by dpkg

```
sudo su 
dpkg --purge viber
```

3- Installed compiled,

```
sudo su
cd <uncompressed directory>
make clean
make uninstall
```